# can a graphic card be emulated with the cpu and ram

Tags: graphics, core-graphics, system, cpu

can a graphic card be sort-of "emulated" so the system can show display without a graphics card when it starts up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Such a thing is called a "virtual framebuffer".